# Hanging a 20lbs lamp from a concrete ceiling, what to be aware of?

Tags: concrete, ceiling, drill, hanging, lamp

I’m trying to drill a hole into the concrete ceiling in my apartment to first insert a hook, then hang the lamp through. The lamp is a plug-in btw.

Just wondering what are the necessary tools and precautions I should consider?! The lamp is 20lbs, Should I be worried that the ceiling will break?! Where should I drill
(if that even matters for a 20lbs weight)? What hooks should I use? Etc., etc.

Thank you so much for helping!!!

Comment: are you allowed to drill into the ceiling in your apartment?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a hammer action drill, masonry drill bit, and a masonry anchor bolts hook (search for expansion hook and concrete or ask at a hardware store). 20lb isn't that much but given it's going to be overhead I'd probably over do the connection.

It's going to be a pig to drill upwards into concrete but if you have a good drill and new drill bit it's doable.

You probably want glasses and a mask as drilling into the ceiling is going to create a lot of dust that will fall onto you.

Comment: Part of the question involves hardware. You might mention what you're recommending.

Comment: I've used lag shields and lag hooks for similar projects.  Get an old  clear Tupperware  cover or cut a tennis ball in half and  drill a hole in the center. Place the cover or half ball  over the starter hole and continue to drill, letting the cover or ball catch the dust.

Comment: Or have a helper with a vacuum get the dust as you drill.

Comment: @JACK that's a _great_ idea! I'll have to keep that in mind.

Comment: @FreeMan  I cut a basketball in half for when using a 5 or 6" hole saw for recessed lights... Glad you like it.